# How to insert sql parameter inside a text query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlcommand, sqlparameter

I'm trying to pass a parameter to a sql query (in c#) but the parameter is inside a text block:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"EXEC sp_helptext N'dbo.@spname';");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@spname", "StoredProcedureName");
```

If I use the stored procedure name directly on query it works fine, but if I pass the parameter it does not work.

Does anyone know how to do this correcty ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("EXEC sp_helptext @spname");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@spname", "dbo.StoredProcedureName");
```

But using

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_helptext");
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@objname", "dbo.StoredProcedureName");
```

is a better choice

Comment: I already try it and doesnt work. I need to pass a text paremether to sp_helptext

Comment: That solution will works fine but, i have a long query and the execution of sp_helptext is somewhere in the midle of the query, i cant execute it separatly

Comment: All right, i made a few corrections to my query and your first answer works fine with it. Thanks podiluska